# Get user appointments in owa

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-web-app

I'm able to read the mail and appointments on read.

Is there a way to read all the future appointments of the user?.
I'm using [owa mail app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161135.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can use EWS, see [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information. Also you may consider using Office 365 API, see [Office 365 API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog) in MSDN.

Comment: the response of ews mentioned is just count of the items in the folder. I want to read the details of the future appointments.